# How do I configure my Azure Function's environment so that I can use the CosmosDB client in Python code?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-static-web-app

I am building an Azure Static App with an API written in Python. I'd like to use the Cosmos Client. I'm able to configure my local machine so that local development works:

- I installed Azure Cosmos into the Python virtual environment: `pip install azure-cosmos`
- Inside the Python code, I create and use the client

```
from azure.cosmos import cosmos_client

cosmos_client.CosmosClient(...)
```

- If I launch `swa` from within the Python virtual environment, things work: `(.venv) $ swa start ...`
- I've added the Cosmos Keys to the app's configuration.

But I'm unable to get this code to work in production. I deployed the the code, and the function fails. When I check Application Insights, I see error messages:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.my_commands Result:
> Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cosmos'.

I assume that I must need to run a command or add something to `requirements.txt`, but I cannot find out what it is.

Comment: In your `requirements.txt` have you added this two `azure-functions`
`azure.cosmosdb=xx.xx` .

Comment: Hello @RyeGrain ,Could you please let us know if you have created artifacts using this `cmd` :- `pip install --target="<PROJECT_DIR>/.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r requirements.txt` and try to deploy and test

Comment: That fixed it. I added `azure-cosmos==4.2.0`. Please type this up and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue got resolved !!Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume that I must need to run a command or add something to
> requirements.txt, but I cannot find out what it is.

To fix this make sure that you have added the below in your `requirements.txt` file

```
azure-functions 
azure-cosmos==x.x.x
```

For more information please refer this [***`GitHub`***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/617#issuecomment-594924909) issue & [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363636/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-azure-cosmosdb).

Comment: For those of you who are new to this, like me, the important lesson is that the lines in `requirements.txt` match what you provided to `pip`.